# how to use an original app class in a helper class like DB or Auth on laravel 4

Tags: php, class, laravel-4

I create an helper class where I put some functions. It works fine till I use an other class on it:

```
namespace Helpers;
class Helper {
    public static function helloWorld()
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
    public static function accessPermission($role, $filtre)
    {
        $jointure_session = DB::table('jointure_session')
        ->where('session_type',$role)
        ->where($filtre,1)
        ->get();
        foreach ($jointure_session as $value_jointure_session) {
            return 'Allow '.$filtre;
        }
    }
}
```

I have an error because the DB class is not found.

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>   Class 'Helpers\DB' not found

Any Idea?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: From the error message it's no the DB that is not found but your own class. Where does the error message happen?

Comment: Sorry, now I put the right error.

Comment: Below the namespace put this `use DB;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Either you list the external clases in the top of your file with the world `use`:

```
<?php namespace Helpers;

use DB;

class Helper {

    public static function helloWorld()
    {
        return DB::foo();
    }
}
```

Either you scape the external classes with `\`:

```
<?php namespace Helpers;

class Helper {

    public static function helloWorld()
    {
        return \DB::foo();
    }
}
```

BTW, for simple functions you don't need to create a class. You can include your functions in a plain php file and load that file with composer. That way you avoid the namespace troubles you are having. i.e:

```
//File: resources/helpers.php
function helloWorld()
{
    return DB::foo();
}
```

To load the file add this to your `composer.json` file

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "resources/helpers.php"
    ],
},
```